# JSON binding in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, imodelbinder

The ASP.NET Core 6 Web API takes a view model that has a string property of `Status`. It turns out the `Status` internally is an enum called `StatusEnum`:

```
public enum StatusEnum
{
    Pending = 1,
    InProgress = 2,
    Completed = 3,
    Failed = 4,
    OnHold = 5
}

public class TaskViewModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
}
```

All the C# code is expecting this `Status` to be the numeric value as a string ("1", "2", ...) but sometimes the client sends in the string name value ("Pending", "InProgress"), etc.

How would I go about creating a custom binding to convert the string name to the numeric value as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1) Add `JsonStringEnumConverter` in your application startup
routine

Option 2) Decorate the enum in question with
`[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter<MyEnum>))]`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-8-0#enums-as-strings

Edit: I'd missed that you said *sometimes* the client sends a string representation. With the behaviours provided in the framework it's one or the other, you'd have to customise to allow either - or just tell the clients not to do that. Requiring them to obey a reasonable API contract is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  For what it's worth, I am the frontend developer now.  We lost our last frontend developer a few months back and I am just trying to do a CYA on this one.  I don't know, nor do I have the time to go find out 100%, all the places the frontend calls this endpoint.